# Basic Algorithm Scripting: Finders Keepers challenge

Tags: javascript

Could someone please tell me why FCC is not accepting my solution, even though it passes all the tests?

Below is the link to the challenge, but I will post the question and tests here to comply better with the community.

FCC Chalenge:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-algorithm-scripting/finders-keepers

Basic Algorithm Scripting: Finders Keepers

Create a function that looks through an array (first argument) and returns the first element in the array that passes a truth test (second argument). If no element passes the test, return undefined.

`findElement([1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10], function(num) { return num % 2 === 0; })` should return 8.

`findElement([1, 3, 5, 9], function(num) { return num % 2 === 0; })` should return undefined.

I have returned the solution as per below:

```
function findElement(arr, func) {
  "use strict"
  return arr.filter(num => func(num)).toString('').substring(1,0);
}

console.log(findElement([1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10], num => num % 2 === 0));
// It returns 8 as expected...
```

The outcome of `console.log(findElement([1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10], num => num % 2 === 0));` is 8 as expected, but for some reason it does no pass the test.

I would like to know if I am doing something wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Change your predicate to `num => num > 100` (as an example), no elements in your array match this. You should be getting `undefined` if that is the case.

Comment: And also capturing only the first character from the result is more than hackish, the function fails when the number to return contains two or more digits. And the return value is a string, a number was expected.

Comment: Hello sir. I am getting 8 as an outcome of ```console.log(findElement([1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10], num => num % 2 === 0))```. Here is the Output screen using quokka in VSCode: ```8 ​​​​​at ​​​findElement([ 1, 3, 5, 8...​​​ ​fcc.js:39:2​```

Comment: I will fix regarding only getting the first character. But the point is that the test should return 8 and it's returning 8 in this case. I did not think about this issue with the amount of characters. Thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: But "_returns the first element in the array [of numbers]_" was required, you're returning a string ...

Comment: Ok, and what about capturing the first value like this? ```function findElement(arr, func) {
    "use strict"
   let array = arr.filter(num => func(num));
   let [a] = array
   return a;
   ;
  }
  
  console.log(findElement([1, 3, 5, 800, 9, 10], num => num % 2 === 0));```

Comment: Take a look at Nick's answer, `filter` is not the best tool for this task. Considering ex. the length of the passed array could be more than million, `filter` iterates all the members, whereas a good algorithm would stop at the first match.

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant thanks for this insight! So you are telling me that by your explanation using the ```.find()``` method here will make the algorithm run much lighter than with my solution? Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Yes, `filter` always iterates through the entire array, it can't be stopped when the the first match is found. Also it returns an array, which is unnecessary heavy for the task where a single value is required. Performance is not an issue with arrays of just few members, but when creating (common) algorithms, it's good to think about all possible use-cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few issues. Currently, you're returning a portion of a string (which may not include your entire result), when really you should be returning the entire value of the first element which matches your predicate (ie: the function passed through). This means that you're returning a string rather than a number, which already is incorrect. Also, you are not returning `undefined` when the passed-through function doesn't match any values.

Instead, consider changing your code so that it either grabs the first element from the array returned by `.filter()` (by targeting index `[0]`) or by using the `.find()` method (which will stop looping once it has found it's value) like so:

```js
function findElement(arr, func) {
  "use strict"
  return arr.find(func); // non point-free version: arr.find(n => func(n))
}

console.log(findElement([1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10], num => num % 2 === 0)); // 8
console.log(findElement([1, 50], num => num % 2 === 0)); // 50
console.log(findElement([1, 1], num => num % 2 === 0)); // undefined
```

Comment: wow! I have used the following to solve it but It did not occur to me that I would work just by using .find(). Thanks! ```function findElement(arr, func) {
    "use strict"
   let array = arr.filter(num => func(num));
   let [a] = array
   return a;
   ;
  }
  
  console.log(findElement([1, 3, 5, 800, 9, 10], num => num % 2 === 0));```

Comment: @Alioshr nice, that will also work. You can also remove the `let array = ...`, and just do `let [a] = arr.filter(num => func(num));`. But, both will work :)

Comment: Indeed! Thanks! I keep mentally splitting the actions of the function in a way that sometimes I make the code longer then it should because of this. Thanks for you comment @Nick Parsons

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution.

```
const findElement = (arr, func) => arr[arr.map(func).indexOf(true)];
```

Comment: `arr.find()` is better than `arr.map()` or `arr.filter()` as `find` will stop at the first match while `filter` and `map` will iterate through all the values

Answer (score 0):

```
function findElement(arr, func) {

    let truthValue=arr.map(func).indexOf(true);
  
    return arr[truthValue];
}

findElement([1, 2, 3, 4], num => num % 2 === 0);
```

Comment: here I use map() to tansform arr which give array of boolens(true and false) then I use indexOf() to get index of true then I use them in  actual array(arr)) with index of true

Comment: This is a more verbose variant of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63215598/466862) from 2020